# control different instances of a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, anonymous

I have a couple questions about he following code:

```
final Runnable accept = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while (connect == true) {
            try {
                sock = servsock.accept();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
};

new Thread(accept).start();        //creates new instance every time i want to run accept()
```

See, every time I want to run 'accept', I create a new thread instance and start it. Can someone tell me how to stop one of these threads? Like, how do I identify the thread? Should I rather use an array of threads?

Comment: The expression `new Thread()` resolves to a reference to a new `Thread` object. Store that in a variable and you'll have access to it later  on.

Comment: maybe you want to use a singleton?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to accept sockets on a ServerSocket is to run the accept loop in 1 thread, and then pass off the newly spawned/accepted socket to another thread.

How to stop your threads? Easiest, best way is to close the Sockets that they are listening on.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using JDK 7? How about this approach?

```
   ExecutorService tPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);  
   InterruptableTask task = new InterruptableTask();  

   Map<Integer, InterruptableTask> tasks = new HashMap<Integer, InterruptableTask>();  
   tasks.put(0, task);  

   Future future = tPool.submit(task);
   // something is executed here...

   InterruptableTask it = tasks.get(0);
   it.suspend();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to maintain a thread pool look at java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService and java.util.concurrent.Executors there web is well stocked with examples of their use.